# How to Avoid needing to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH ld : collect2 fails

Tags: gcc, linker, native-maven-plugin

Is there a command line option equivalent to LD_LIBRARY_PATH for linking?

I build native via native-maven-plugin which lack support for setting environment variables and setting prior to maven breaks my other modules.  I need to either

- find an alternative to native-maven-plugin (long term solution)
- find a command line option to add required path to linker search

I've tried:

- --library-path
- -L
- --rpath-link, --rpath
- -R

Each time I continue to get the following:

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libsc_fnt.so, needed by 
...lib/libsc_ex.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround

- Forked native-maven-plugin
- created envFactor for gcc compiler
- added ldLibraryParam param to mojo
- set logic that we push value into environment if there's an envFactory and ldLibraryPath is set.
- works on linux with only that one variation in build log

Never did figure out what compiler/linker option was the equivalent.